# How can I conditionally reorder elements of an Excel table with Microsoft Visual Basic (VBA) based on the number of entries in each column?

Tags: vba, date, excel, bloomberg

I have downloaded earnings data from Bloomberg for a large number of assets for one year. The resulting table measures 4 rows and around 3000 columns. Some columns contain four values, some contain two, and some contain only 1 because of the differences in reporting requirements:

- Some companies announce their earnings on an annual basis (31/12: 1 value)
- Some companies announce their earnings on a semi-annual basis (31/6 and 31/12: 2 values)
- Some companies announce their earnings on a quarterly basis (31/3, 31/6, 31/9, 31/12: 4 values)

The table values (B17:DKZ20) are preceded by one column of announcement dates (A17:A20), which correspond to the quarterly announcements of the first company in my list, because this is the highest possible frequency and covers all possible dates for earnings announcements (31/03; 31/06; 31/09; 31/12).

Because I used:

```
Range(B17:DKZ17).Formula = "=BDH([Ticker], ""IS_EPS"", [Beginning Date], [End Date], ""Dates, Period"", ""H,M"")"
```

with the optional argument to hide dates in order to display values directly next to each other, which can more clearly be written as:

```
""Dates = Hidden""
```

the table now simply contains the earnings announcements in the order they were made, that is, the dates are displayed correctly for quarterly earnings announcement, but annual announcements are displayed as having been made on the 31/03 (when 31/12 would be correct) and semi-annual announcement are displayed as having been made on 31/03 and 31/6 (when 31/06 and 31/12 would be correct).

What I need to do in order to correct this is:

1. Move the entries from columns with only one entry (annual) three cells down (from cell 1 to cell 4);
2. Move the entries from columns with two entries (semi-annual) from cells 1 and 2 to cells 2 and 4.

How can I use manipulate the table using Visual Basic (VBA) in such a way that steps 1. and 2. are performed? Is there a command to move values or would it have to be conditional cutting and pasting?

Comment: Not all companies have a year end 31/12 so some of your assumptions are not necessarily true. Have you tried with `"Dates=H,Period=M,Days=A,Fill=n.a."`?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the data into a 2D vba array; reorder the data fields to your specifications, then write the array back to the worksheet.  The reading and writing can be done in a single step; and it'll be a lot faster to move things around in the array than on the worksheet.